# Markers in Holoviews

Tags: holoviews

The following script produces a nice scatterplot as in the picture below

```
from holoviews import extension, dim, opts, Scatter
from pandas import read_csv
extension('bokeh')
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/master/penguins.csv'
df = read_csv(url)
scatterplot = Scatter(df, 'flipper_length_mm', ['body_mass_g','island'] )
scatterplot.opts( color=dim('island').str(), cmap=['red','green','blue'] )
```

Now, suppose I want to use markers in place of colors for `island`.

Is there something equivalent to `cmap` (as in the last line of the script above) for `marker`?

[image: Scatterplot with colors]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update the code as below to add markers. I have left the colors as is. If you don't need it, can remove that and just keep the markers alone... You can use markers from [here](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/markers.html)

```
scatterplot.opts( color=dim('island').str(), cmap=['red','green','blue'],
                 marker=dim('island').categorize({'Torgersen':'circle', 'Biscoe':'diamond', 'Dream':'dash'}) )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it works. Strange enough, `categorize` alone does not produce a legend.

Comment: I believe that holoviews picks up the legend from the colors. So, if you want to ONLY use markers, simplest way would be to change the cmap in above to same color.... like so - `cmap=['blue','blue','blue']`. This will give you legend with the different markers, but same color. Bit of a hack, but easy solution :-)

Comment: Is there anyway to do this where the markers change their color based on 'flipper_length_mm` on a continuous colormap (like viridis), and their marker is based on the `island` (like above), and there is a legend that distinguishes between marker/island, and a colorbar that shows the 'flipper_length_mm`?